S3 policy to create a public write-only bucket that the account owner can read
I'm trying to configure an S3 bucket that the public can drop files into (but not read, delete or list) and that the root user can have full access to. I cant find how to code the policy to match both of those requirements at the same time.
I've tried the following policy, the public can indeed write but not read. However the root user cant see the list of objects in the AWS console I get the error "Insufficient permissions to list objects
After you or your AWS administrator has updated your permissions to allow the s3:ListBucket action, refresh the page".
Changing the order of the "Statement" clauses doesn't help.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MY_ACCOUNT_ID:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME_HERE",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME_HERE/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME_HERE",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME_HERE/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME_HERE",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME_HERE/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


Note that if an unauthenticated user can upload an arbitrary object then that user can effectively delete existing objects if the key to an existing object is known, by simply uploading a new, empty file with that same key.

Amazon S3 buckets are private by default.
Therefore, you only need this policy:
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME_HERE/*"
            ]
        }

This adds the ability for anyone to store an object in the bucket. Therefore, anyone who normally has access to the bucket (eg the owner) will still have that access.
Please note that Deny policies override Allow policies, so your Deny s3:* policy is actually blocking access to everyone, including the owner.
